# Image 403 Forbidden Error

Tags: php, wordpress, image, http-status-code-403

I have a website built with wordpress and uploaded on a linux server. It's been working fine for a long time, but yesterday my website started giving me 403 forbidden errors while loading image resources.

[image]

But when I open that resource in a new tab, it gets loaded successfully. Then I go back to my website, refresh it, and that particular image gets reloaded now.

I don't know what's going on. I need help.

Comment: do u use ssh or ftp? so you can share with us the permissions

Comment: Permission might have changed check for them. Its loading in tab may be due to already non - expired cache.

Comment: try applying 777 for uploads folder

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Incorrect file permissions can cause 403 forbidden error. It makes your web server think that you do not have permission to access these files.**

All folders on your WordPress site should have a file permission of `744` or `755`.
All files on your WordPress site should have a file permission of `644` or `640`

If you have ssh access you can change permissions using this command:

```
chmod -R 755 /var/www/html/yoursite
```

If you are using a ftp client like Filezilla you can select a folder, right click and then select File Permissions from the menu.

**Also the 403 error is caused by a corrupt `.htaccess` file in your WordPress site.**

You can generate a fresh `.htaccess` file by logging into your WordPress admin area and going to `Settings » Permalinks` page.

Comment: Good catch. My .htaccess file was being modified by all in one security plugin. Replacing .htaccess with default wordpress .htaccess file fixed it for me. Thanks

Comment: Great to hear that @Ali. Please accept as correct answer

Answer (score -1):

403 stands for permission denied. You need to check the permissions for those image.